# Extract a subset of files from TreeArtifact as a list of files in bazel?

Tags: bazel, openapi-generator

I'm trying to consume the output of https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel, which happily takes my openapi.json file and generates a tree of source code for python.

Unfortunately I can't use it directly, because I need only the python files in a subdirectory to be used as sources in a py_library rule.

...but it seems to produce a single generated file, which is a `ctx.actions.declare_directory` sort of artifact.

I'm flummoxed.  I can make a rule that extracts a subdirectory from that in the same way using `ctx.actions.run_shell`, but since you have to declare every output file in a rule, and the directory is opaque to bazel, I can't declare every output file with an action, so I can't find any way to iterate across the input directory.

Surely, surely, surely there is a way to filter a TreeArtifact by inspection.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally clear how the authors intended for `openapi_generator` to be used, because in general directory outputs are not well supported as outputs of targets themselves. E.g. `py_library` and `java_library` don't know to look inside the directory outputs of other targets. At least for now, typically directory outputs are more for passing things between actions within the implementations of rules.

Indeed there's an open issue for this on OpenAPI: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel/issues/22

And there's a related Bazel bug about taking directory outputs as `srcs`, at least for the Java rules: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11996

Compare to protocol buffers, for example, where (usually) a .proto file corresponds to 1 output python file (`foo.proto` -> `foo_pb2.py`), so the outputs can be derived from the `py_proto_library`'s `srcs` directly.

Anyway, one workaround is to explicitly list the expected output files:

`defs.bzl`:

```py
def _get_openapi_files(ctx):
  for out in ctx.outputs.outs:
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
      inputs = ctx.files.src,
      outputs = [out],
      command = "cp {src} {dst}".format(
          src = ctx.files.src[0].path + "/" + out.short_path,
          dst = out.path,
      ),
    )
  return DefaultInfo(files = depset(ctx.outputs.outs))

get_openapi_files = rule(
  implementation = _get_openapi_files,
  attrs = {
    "src": attr.label(mandatory = True),
    "outs": attr.output_list(mandatory = True),
  },
)
```

`BUILD`:

```py
load("@openapi_tools_generator_bazel//:defs.bzl", "openapi_generator")
load(":defs.bzl", "get_openapi_files")

openapi_generator(
    name = "gen_petstore_python",
    generator = "python",
    spec = "petstore.yaml",
)

get_openapi_files(
  name = "get_petstore_python_files",
  src = ":gen_petstore_python",
  outs = [
    "openapi_client/models/__init__.py",
    "openapi_client/apis/__init__.py",
    "openapi_client/__init__.py",
    "openapi_client/model_utils.py",
    "openapi_client/api/__init__.py",
    "openapi_client/api/pets_api.py",
    "openapi_client/rest.py",
    "openapi_client/configuration.py",
    "openapi_client/exceptions.py",
    "openapi_client/api_client.py",
    "openapi_client/model/__init__.py",
    "openapi_client/model/pets.py",
    "openapi_client/model/pet.py",
    "openapi_client/model/error.py",
  ],
)

py_library(
  name = "petstore_python",
  srcs = [":get_petstore_python_files"],
)

py_binary(
  name = "petstore_main",
  srcs = [":petstore_main.py"],
  deps = [":petstore_python"],
)
```

`petstore_main.py`:

```py
from openapi_client.model import pet

p = pet.Pet(123, "lassie")
print(p)
```

`petstore.yaml` is https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel/blob/fb7e302de4597277bea12757836f2ce988c805ee/internal/test/petstore.yaml

```
$ bazel run petstore_main
INFO: Analyzed target //:petstore_main (45 packages loaded, 600 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:petstore_main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/petstore_main
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.150s, Critical Path: 1.42s
INFO: 20 processes: 5 internal, 15 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 20 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 20 total actions
{'id': 123, 'name': 'lassie'}
```

The obvious downside is that any time you make a modification to the API definition that changes the what files are created, you have to go and update the BUILD file. And creating the list of output files might be tedious if you have a lot of api definitions.

Another workaround is to take advantage of the fact that Python doesn't really get compiled in the build system, and play some symlink tricks. However, this requires setting `--experimental_allow_unresolved_symlinks` (which can be added to the `.bazelrc` file):

`defs.bzl`:

```py
def _symlink_openapi_files_impl(ctx):
  symlink = ctx.actions.declare_symlink("openapi_client")
  ctx.actions.symlink(
      output = symlink,
      target_path = ctx.files.src[0].path + "/openapi_client")

  return [
      DefaultInfo(
          default_runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = ctx.files.src + [symlink])),
      PyInfo(transitive_sources = depset(ctx.files.src)),
  ]

symlink_openapi_files = rule(
  implementation = _symlink_openapi_files_impl,
  attrs = {
    "src": attr.label(mandatory = True),
  },
)
```

`BUILD`:

```py
load("@openapi_tools_generator_bazel//:defs.bzl", "openapi_generator")
load(":defs.bzl", "symlink_openapi_files")

openapi_generator(
    name = "gen_petstore_python",
    generator = "python",
    spec = "petstore.yaml",
)

symlink_openapi_files(
  name = "symlink_petstore_python_files",
  src = ":gen_petstore_python",
)

py_binary(
  name = "petstore_main",
  srcs = [":petstore_main.py"],
  deps = [":symlink_petstore_python_files"],
)
```

```
$ bazel run petstore_main --experimental_allow_unresolved_symlinks
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
INFO: Analyzed target //:petstore_main (48 packages loaded, 634 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:petstore_main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/petstore_main
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.797s, Critical Path: 1.38s
INFO: 7 processes: 6 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 7 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 7 total actions
{'id': 123, 'name': 'lassie'}
```

Another alternative is to use a [repository rule](https://bazel.build/extending/repo) to generate the files. A repository rule can do things outside the regular rule rule / target execution model like generating BUILD files, however this amounts to basically reimplementing OpenAPI's Bazel integration.

Comment: Java rules support `.srcjar` files in `srcs`, which are zip files containing java source. So you could write a rule to archive the OpenAPI output and pass that result into a `java_library` or similar.

Comment: i give an example here of how to do that for the java rules and openapi: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel/issues/22#issuecomment-1221058761

as far as i know the python rules don't have an equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Good response from ahumesky!  It turns out at least in the Python case that there's *another* way.  One way is to do as ahumesky says and explicitly declare all the output files in a separate rule, and that works well.  Another way is to declare your own rule which *can* accept a TreeArtifact, but the sneaky way to do it is wrap the output in a `PyInfo` provider, as is done at https://github.com/jvolkman/rules_pycross/blob/main/pycross/private/wheel_library.bzl, which I cannibalized for this, although I will probably change to using the symlink approach above:

```
def _python_client_from_openapi_impl(ctx):
    """Rule that generates the python library from the openapi-generator source
    directory (a tree)"""
    output = ctx.actions.declare_directory(ctx.attr.package_name)  # label.name)
    # because the openapi generator imports the package directly ("import [packagename]")
    # and names things appropriately, we can't so easily just use it fully-qualified;
    # we'll have to add it to the import path.
    # If the package is 'jwt_generator/service', this adds '__main__/jwt_generator/service'
    # to the import path, so if the client packagename was "jwt_client", you can just
    # import jwt_client
    imp = paths.join(
        ctx.label.workspace_name or ctx.workspace_name,
        ctx.label.package,
    )
    print(imp)
    imports = depset(
        direct=[imp], transitive=[d[PyInfo].imports for d in ctx.attr.deps]
    )
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs=[output],
        inputs=ctx.files.srcs,
        command="cp -r {}/{}/* {}".format(
            ctx.files.srcs[0].path, ctx.attr.package_name, output.path
        ),
    )
    # now all the relative python sources are in our output directory
    transitive_sources = depset(direct=[output], transitive=[])
    # runfiles (https://bazel.build/rules/lib/runfiles)
    # "a set of files required at runtime execution" -- which in the case of
    # interpreted languages generally means much of the source
    runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files=[output])
    return [
        DefaultInfo(files=depset([output]), runfiles=runfiles),
        PyInfo(
            has_py2_only_sources=False,
            has_py3_only_sources=True,
            imports=imports,
            transitive_sources=transitive_sources,
        ),
    ]


python_client_from_openapi = rule(
    implementation=_python_client_from_openapi_impl,
    attrs={
        "srcs": attr.label(allow_files=True, doc="Output of openapi_client rule"),
        "package_name": attr.string(),
        "deps": attr.label_list(
            doc="A list of the client's dependencies; typically just urllib3 and python-dateutil",
            providers=[DefaultInfo, PyInfo],
        ),
    },
)
```

This actually works pretty well although it was a sort of first-try hack and not robust/efficient, so I'm going to probably use a combination of the two.

Comment: Interesting, using just `PyInfo` was the first thing I looked at, looks like the extra thing that was needed was setting `imports`